# Javascript value of button text after change

Tags: javascript

Website has a button with text that changes dynamically.

Elements before button text change:

```
<button _ngcontent-wex-c70="" 
    class="btn btn-wait buy font-family-title height-70 pp-sun-ins"><label _ngcontent-wex-c70="" translate="" 
    class="font-family-title label">BUY</label>
</button>
```

Elements after button text change:

```
<button _ngcontent-wex-c70="" 
    class="btn btn-root press font-family-title pp-sun-ins"><span _ngcontent-wex-c70="" 
    class="d-power power-column justify-content-center align-items-center"><label _ngcontent-wex-c70="" translate="">EXIT NOW</label><label _ngcontent-wex-c70="" 
    class="price"><span _ngcontent-wex-c70="" 
    class="cost">1.46</span><i _ngcontent-wex-c70="" 
    class="UNT"></i></label></span>
</button>
```

I can get the value of cost using this method:

```
<script>
    var cost = document.getElementsByClassName("cost")[0].innerText;
    console.log("my cost is: "+cost)
</script>
```

This works from the online JavaScript tester at "https://jsfiddle.net/"

However on the Chrome browser the following error is returned:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'innertext')
```

I can confirm that the elements shown from "Elements after button text change" are present using the Developer Elements Inspector.

In the Chrome browser console I only run the following code:

```
var cost = document.getElementsByClassName("cost")[0].innerText;
console.log("my cost is: "+cost)
```

Comment: *"I can confirm that the elements shown [...] are present"* - The error suggests otherwise.  When you test `document.getElementsByClassName("cost")`, what does it return?  Are you running this code when the page loads?  Some time later?  Is it on the page itself, or you're manually typing/pasting it into the console?

Comment: So you are trying to select the element before it exists on the page. It is like looking for a person before they walk into a room. You are not going to find them.

Comment: I can confirm the elements that I execute the javacode multiple times while viewing the contents of the webpage button text change.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to wait for the DOM to load

```
window.onload = function() {
  var cost = document.getElementsByClassName("cost")[0].innerText;
  console.log("my cost is: "+cost);
}
```

Comment: I execute the javacode multiple times while viewing the contents of the webpage button text change and still get the same, the loading should have completed if I can view the changes live on the webpage correct?

Answer (score 0):

Just wait for the document to load.
above solution could be workable or try this, it's gonna work.

```html
<script>
    var cost = document.getElementsByClassName("cost")[0]?.innerText;
    console.log("my cost is: "+cost)
</script>
```